# How to identify the only different number from a list of same numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures, linear-search

Assalamualaikum (peace be upon you)

If in the list of n numbers, n-1 numbers are identical  and only one number is unique,then, is there any way, other than linear search to identify the identical number as well as the unique number of the list?

Comment: Doing better than ```O(N)``` is impossible

Comment: First sort the list.  Then you only have to check three numbers.  The first, the last and one somewhere in between, say the second.  Two of the three will match the n-1 identical numbers.  The third of the three will be unique.  Pick a sorting method that works well on a list with a lot of matches.

Comment: @rossum won't that be worse as in N lg N?

Comment: Pick an algorithm where an almost sorted array is the best case; only one element is out of position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the list at least once. so the algorithm is at least of `O(n)`, and linear search as you mentioned it does the work for you.